# MassTransit: Single Direct Exchange with Multiple Queues

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to use MassTransit with an existing RabbitMQ server, which has a single direct exchange, with two queues. However, I can't seem to get this setup to work. I tried different configurations in code, but without any success. It's a single application which receives messages from both queues. This application only focuses on the consuming part of the queues.

I would post some code, but honestly I have no idea which piece of code I should use as the starting point, so hopefully someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: I don’t think MassTransit is the right tool for that. MassTransit uses message type-based routing with topology by convention and mainly meant to be used to communicate with other applications that also use MassTransit but not as a glorified RMQ client.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example that shows how to use direct exchanges with routing keys:

https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct

You'll still need to either send a supported message envelope, or use the RawJson serializer.

Comment: Is there an up-to-date version of the samples? It's still using 5.5.4, while the latest version is 7.0.3. `BindMessageExchanges` does not exist in newer versions, and I couldn't find an equivalent.

Comment: `ConfigureConsumeTopology`